# Creating completeness meter (Status display) in Xamarin

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to design a control that displays current status of a process, like this image below.

[image: Status Control]

So, we have a circular display of status with colored sections for milestones or checkpoints. In the image, we are already through the first two stages, and third stage is 70% done.

I know there is a control in Jquery that was pretty similar. But I am not sure, if there is a third party control in Xamarin Forms that I can use. If there is no third party control, how should I proceed with the design.

Should I just create images for different stages and display the image? Or should I create a custom control which can take two values, "milestone" and "percentage_complete", and then design maybe a pie chart on the fly?

Comment: I would definitely go for different images, that's easy to implement and nice and clean in terms of maintainability. The disadvantage is that if you need a new process, you will need to re-create (most if not all of) the images. But imo, that's better than lots of work to build such an complex control with custom renderers.

Comment: Easiest way is to create different images and its easy maintenance... If you want this in harder way, you can try SkiaSharp for 2d drawing https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/drawing/

Comment: @DennisSchröer That's what my first thought was. But then I remembered there was a control in Jquery similar to this one. So, I thought, I can try that. Plus image might get tricky with resolution changes of different mobile devices. I am just looking for a possible solution. Otherwise, I will obviously just do images as that seems to be the laziest way out.

Comment: What about using a very good plugin to design charts, then use it to make your gauge? Take a look at this, I use and recommend:
https://blog.xamarin.com/microcharts-elegant-cross-platform-charts-for-any-app/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `NGraphics` w/ `NControl` you can create a "vector" version of your "completeness meter" without creating platform renderers or needing to add libraries like `Skia` to your project.

Note: SkiaSharp and other native 2d/3d libraries are great, but add an lot of overhead to an app and if you do not need all their features then the bloat (app size, memory usage, initialization time, etc...) is not worth it (IMHO).

re: https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics

I stripped down a `MultiSegmentProgressControl` that I did to show you the basics of the arc drawing. The full version that I did allows you to add and animate multiple segments, displaying percentages, break-out segments on touch, etc...

Using `NControl` you can create composite controls with touch elements, so it is up to you on how far you need to take it.

re: https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl

[image]

```
public class MultiSegmentProgressControl2 : NControlView
{
    double ringWidth = 50;
    double ringInnerWidth = 100;
    SolidBrush redBush = new SolidBrush(Colors.Red);
    RadialGradientBrush redSegmentBrush = new RadialGradientBrush(
            new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            new Size(.75, .75),
            Colors.LightGray,
            Colors.Red);
    SolidBrush blueBush = new SolidBrush(Colors.Blue);
    RadialGradientBrush blueSegmentBrush = new RadialGradientBrush(
            new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            new Size(.75, .75),
            Colors.LightGray,
            Colors.Green);

    Tuple<double, double> _redSegment;
    public Tuple<double, double> RedSegment { get { return _redSegment; } set { _redSegment = value; Invalidate(); } }
    Tuple<double, double> _greenSegment;
    public Tuple<double, double> GreenSegment { get { return _greenSegment; } set { _greenSegment = value; Invalidate(); } }

    public override void Draw(ICanvas canvas, Rect rect)
    {
        canvas.FillEllipse(rect.TopLeft, rect.Size, Colors.Gray);
        var n = rect;
        n.X += ringWidth;
        n.Y = n.X;
        n.Width -= ringWidth * 2;
        n.Height = n.Width;
        var i = n;
        canvas.FillEllipse(n.TopLeft, n.Size, Colors.LightGray);
        n.X += ringInnerWidth;
        n.Y = n.X;
        n.Width -= ringInnerWidth * 2;
        n.Height = n.Width;
        canvas.FillEllipse(n.TopLeft, n.Size, Colors.White);

        var r = rect.Width / 2;
        DrawSegment(canvas, rect, ringWidth, redBush, r, _redSegment.Item1, _redSegment.Item2);
        DrawSegment(canvas, i, ringInnerWidth, redSegmentBrush, r - ringWidth, _redSegment.Item1, _redSegment.Item2);
        DrawSegment(canvas, rect, ringWidth, blueBush, r, _greenSegment.Item1, _greenSegment.Item2);
        DrawSegment(canvas, i, ringInnerWidth, blueSegmentBrush, r - ringWidth, _greenSegment.Item1, _greenSegment.Item2);
    }

    void DrawSegment(ICanvas canvas, Rect rect, double width, Brush brush, double r, double s, double f)
    {
        canvas.DrawPath(new PathOp[]{
            new MoveTo(SegmentEdgePoint(rect.Center, r, s)),
            new ArcTo(new Size(rect.Height / 2, rect.Width / 2), false, true, SegmentEdgePoint(rect.Center, r, f)),
            new LineTo(SegmentEdgePoint(rect.Center, r - width, f)),
            new ArcTo(new Size(r, r), false, false, SegmentEdgePoint(rect.Center, r - width, s)),
            new LineTo(SegmentEdgePoint(rect.Center, r, s)),
            new ClosePath()
        }, null, brush);
    }

    Point SegmentEdgePoint(Point c, double r, double d)
    {
        return new Point(
            c.X + r * Math.Cos(d * Math.PI / 180),
            c.Y + r * Math.Sin(d * Math.PI / 180)
        );
    }
}
```

When using `NGraphics` I highly recommend using the `NGraphics.Editor`or a Xamarin' WorkBook to interactively design your control:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. This works perfect. Sorry, I was out of town, so never got to check it. But finally checked it. Perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find an already completed solution (highly recommended if you can find one!) then creating a control with incremental calls to a graphics library with DrawSegment calls might work.

1. Draw a segment for each part of the strongly coloured outer ring
   sections,
2. Draw a segment with reduced radius for the inner, dimly coloured
   sections,
3. Draw a white circle for the centre white pad.

Good luck!